# Elasticsearch : Retrieve long text field from a document

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a document indexed in ES. This document have 3 text fields `F1`, `F2` and `F3`.

When I try to search this document using the Java API, I only have the value for fields `F1` and `F2`, and field `F3` appears empty.

```
QueryBuilder query =  //Some query

SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index)
                .addDocValueField("F1.keyword")
                .addDocValueField("F2.keyword")
                .addDocValueField("F3.keyword")
                .setQuery(query)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();

SearchHit hit = response.getHits().getAt(0);

System.out.println("F1 : "+hit.getField("F1.keyword").getValue());
System.out.println("F2 : "+hit.getField("F2.keyword").getValue());
System.out.println("F3 : "+hit.getField("F3.keyword").getValue()); // empty
```

My field `F3` can be very long. In the document I use for the tests, it does >300 characters, and can be way longer.

My index mapping is :

```
"mappings": {
      "MyIndex": {
        "properties": {
          "F1": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "F2": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "F3": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

So I updated the `ignore_above` field in mapping for `F3` up to 20000 (might be a bad idea ?), but I still have the same behavior.

What is the problem, and what is the correct way to do this ?

Notes :

- Using ES 5.6.3
- I don't need to do any analysis / term search on the field `F3`, only retrieving it's value when a query match `F1` or `F2`.
- I will have a small number of document of this kind, so efficiency would not be a big issue

EDIT :

Strange thing is that I have the expected result when I request elasticsearch with my browser with query :

```
http://localhost:9200/MyIndex/_search?pretty=true?{"query": {"match_all": {}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Elasticsearch, the default behavior maps text strings into two different Elasticsearch types: `text` and `keyword`. They are different things, used for different purposes, mainly it's that `text` is a full text search field, while `keyword` is like a structured constant value. Read more in [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/mapping-types.html)

In your case, the default inclusion of the `keyword` field doesn't look helpful. In your queries, you should just grab the "regular" `F3` field, and/or the regular fields for `F1` and `F2` also.

Last, I'm not super familiar with the ES Java client, but if you want to do source filtering (i.e. get only a subset of values back from your request), I don't think `addDocValueField()` is right. Check out: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/5.6/java-rest-high-search.html#_source_filtering

Comment: It works well with the `setFetchSource()` in place of `addDocValueField()` and without using the `.keywords`. Thank you